# Hive: script doesn't identify database which is already created

Tags: hive, hiveql

I wrote a Hive script and tried running on the terminal but that gave me error. It says there is no such database.

What I did is I have created a database `stocks` in hive. I have created a file `myscript.sql` in the local file system and I have these statements in it:

```
use stocks;
create table customer ( id int, name string) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;
```

When I execute this file from terminal using

```
hive -f myscript.sql
```

I get the error

> "stocks" database does not exists.

Comment: what happens if you type `show databases;`?

Comment: Either you didn't create it or you are connecting to a different metastore

Comment: I got the problem resolved. I had to upgrade the hive version to 0.13